# Align index after apply agroupby to data

Tags: python, pandas

I read such an example from "10 minutes in pandas"

```
#+begin_src ipython :session alinbx :results output
 df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
                          'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                    'B': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
                          'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
                    'C': np.random.randn(8),
                    'D': np.random.randn(8)})
print(df)
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:      A      B         C         D
: 0  foo    one  0.556718  0.948458
: 1  bar    one  0.136203 -0.622480
: 2  foo    two -1.472084 -1.269811
: 3  bar  three  0.825478 -0.313981
: 4  foo    two -0.179626 -1.176105
: 5  bar    two -0.857654  2.008154
: 6  foo    one  0.932524  0.070442
: 7  foo  three  1.397533  1.050003
```

Grouping and then applying the sum() function to the resulting groups.

```
#+begin_src ipython :session alinbx :results output
print(df.groupby('A').sum())
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:             C         D
: A
: bar  0.104028  1.071693
: foo  1.235065 -0.397013
```

The problem is that A is not aligned with B C.

Other example, Grouping by multiple columns forms a hierarchical index, and again we can apply the sum function

```
#+begin_src ipython :session alinbx :results output
print(df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum())
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
:                   C         D
: A   B
: bar one    0.136203 -0.622480
:     three  0.825478 -0.313981
:     two   -0.857654  2.008154
: foo one    1.489242  1.018899
:     three  1.397533  1.050003
:     two   -1.651711 -2.445916
```

A, B are also not aligned with C, D

How could solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `as_index=False` parameter to [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

> **as_index : bool**, default True
>
> For aggregated output, return object with group labels as the index. Only relevant for DataFrame input. as_index=False is effectively “SQL-style” grouped output.

```
print(df.groupby('A', as_index=False).sum())

print(df.groupby(['A', 'B'], as_index=False).sum())
```

It working nice in mainly aggregate functions like `sum`, `mean`, `count`, `median`, `first`, `last`.

But not working with `size`, there is necessary add `.reset_index(name='count')`.

Answer (score 4):

You can just use [pandas.DataFrame.reset_index()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

`print(df.groupby(['A', 'B']).sum().reset_index())`